# Usage of 'any' before more and comparative degrees

Tags: polarity-items

Could anyone please tell me what is the role of any in this sentence and can I leave out ***any*** in the sentence?

> I love to read books. I have books of many writers. I have a book named 'Gitanjali' written by Rabindranath Tagore and a book named 'Hamlet' written by William Shakespeare and many more books. I don't need (***any***) more books.

I think I can leave out any in the above sentence.

Here is another example:

> Me: Hey dad, I know you are going for a hike. I have given five packets of biscuits in your bag. Do you need (**any**) more packets of biscuits?
>
> Dad: No no that's enough. I don't need (**any**) more packets of biscuits.

I think I can also leave out **any** in both the above sentences.

And one more question, what does it mean when we use ***any*** before comparative degrees. Is it necessary to use any before comparative degrees can I leave it out? I  don't often use ***any*** before comparative degrees.

Here is the example:

> John: Yesterday, we lost the match to Manchester United. Our strikers were out of form. Could it have been ***any*** better if the coach had substituted them? What do you think Mani?
>
> Me: No, I don't think it could be ***any*** better because all the players were out of form.

Comment: I think you can leave out ***any*** in all your examples. It's just an optional "intensifier" for the relevant "comparator" that follows *(more, better, etc.)*, which could equally be expressed by a longer phrase in many contexts *(I don't need **even one** more book, I doubt it would have been **the least bit** better if he'd used substitutes).*

Comment: As an aside "I have given five packets of biscuits in your bag" sounds very non-fluent.  You could say "I have given five packets of biscuits" but it means something like "I donated five packets of biscuits" or "I gave away five packets of biscuits", and "in your bag" sounds like it was where you were when you donated them!  More fluent would be "I put five packets of biscuits in your bag" or "I gave *you* five packets of biscuits in your bag."